# how to set a custom config value for sphinx in conf.py? (e.g., for sphinx.ext.ifconfig)

Tags: python-sphinx

[I split the original question into two after more testing and research]

I defined my own configuration value in conf.py and wrote a minimal extension to make it visible from rst files.

in conf.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.ifconfig', 'myExt']
testlevel = 2
```

in a local myExt.py:

```
def setup(app):
   app.add_config_value('testlevel', '', True)
```

This works just fine;  test.rst includes:

```
.. ifconfig:: testlevel == 2

    Hurray, it seems to work
```

According to the doc of [sphinx.ext.ifconfig](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/ifconfig.html), it seems possible to call *app.add_config_value* directly from *conf.py*.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to note here:

1. First, the `conf.py` file is just a python file.  The only thing special about it is that Sphinx specifically looks for it and imports it.  You can do anything in this file you could do in a  normal python file.
2. Second, the `conf.py` file [can itself be an extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-extensions).  In other words, it can have a `setup` function that should work the same way as one in an extension.  So if you copy the contents of your extension (`myExt.py`) into the `conf.py` file, it should Just Work (tm).

Comment: Many thanks, Kevin.  I thought I had first tried to put the setup function into conf.py, but that didn't seem to work.  Do I also have to declare extensions=[..., 'conf'] ?

Comment: I don't think so.  At least I don't recall ever having done that, and the documentation seems to indicate that just putting a setup function in conf.py will do the trick.

Comment: conf.py is compiled and evaluated and not __import__'ed as done with those provided in the extensions list. That's no problem, yet. But conf.py definitions are pickled and since it is not a proper module, definitions like <code>class mynode(nodes.Inline, nodes.Element):pass </code> will lead to PicklingError: Can't pickle     : it's not found as...