# How to use config values in templates?

Tags: python-sphinx

I set a config value *big_logo* with a [simple extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709024/how-to-set-a-custom-config-value-for-sphinx-in-conf-py-e-g-for-sphinx-ext-if).  I also tested my way of setting  config values with *sphinx.ext.ifconfig* and it seems to work.

Now, I'd like to use that in a template for layout.html
as follows:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% block header %}
    {%- if big_logo %}
       <div style="background-color: white;>
           <img src="{{ pathto("_static/" + big_logo, 1) }}" alt="logo" />
       </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This doesn't work, however;  *make html* yields:

```
Exception occurred:
File "...", line 7, in block "header"
   <img src="{{ pathto("_static/" + big_logo, 1) }}" alt="logo" />
UndefinedError: 'big_logo' is undefined
```

This seems to be the same as the layout.html of the basic theme:

```
{%- block sidebarlogo %}
  {%- if logo %}
   <p class="logo"><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">
          <img class="logo" src="{{ pathto('_static/' + logo, 1) }}" alt="Logo"/>
```

My only doubt is that *conf.py* doesn't set the variable "logo" but "html_logo".

Any ideas how to use configuration values in templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass the config value [the html context setting](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/config.html#confval-html_context).  From my understanding, only variables [defined by Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/templating.html#global-variables) and variables in this dictionary will be available in the templates.  I'm not sure exactly how this will interact with the way you are setting the config variable, assuming you want to do it like you describe in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709024/how-to-set-a-custom-config-value-for-sphinx-in-conf-py-e-g-for-sphinx-ext-if), but it should be do-able.  Just remember, the `conf.py` file is really just Plain Old Python.