# Get variables in Sphinx templates

Tags: variables, templates, jinja2, python-sphinx

I can't figure out how to get variables into Sphinx documents via a template.  I am certainly making an elementary mistake, but while there is lots of documentation for using Jinja/Flask templates for web service and some documentation for [Sphinx using it](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html), I am having trouble doing the following.   Maybe it's not possible and I'm barking up the wrong tree, but then this is fairly different from how variables work in general in web (as opposed to doc) templates?

I am working within a much larger project.  Suppose in my project's `conf.py` I make a variable, say

```
LANGS = ['en', 'de', 'cn']
```

I know that this works because if I do the docbuild (we have a custom docbuild but I don't think it does anything really crazy other than a customized logger and eating a bunch of 'chatter') with the following line in `conf.py`

```
print len(LANGS)
```

it shows up during the docbuild.

But now of course I want to access this variable in my template.  As far as I can tell, we override `index.rst` with `templates/index.html`, which inherits from the basic layout.html for Sphinx.  And if I do

```
<p>We have {{ LANGS|len }} languages</p>
```

I get

> We have 0 languages

Now, this is weird, because sometimes I can cause an error in the build by referring to variables not defined (though not consistently), so that somehow it 'knows' that the variable is defined but thinks it has length zero.  Or does a "null" variable have length zero automatically?

**How do I get this variable defined - or is it not possible?**

What I *want* to do is then do something for each language in the list (make an outside link, in particular), but I figure there is no point in trying `{% for %}/{% endfor %}` or whatever if I can't get this working.  Maybe Sphinx implements only a subset of Jinja?

Anyway, please help!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709024/how-to-set-a-custom-config-value-for-sphinx-in-conf-py-e-g-for-sphinx-ext-if

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are at least two ways to pass variables to a template:

1. Via [`html_context`](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-html_context):

   > A dictionary of values to pass into the template engine’s context for all pages. Single values can also be put in this dictionary using the -A command-line option of sphinx-build.

   Example:

   ```
   # conf.py:
   html_context = {'num_langs': len(LANGS)}

   <!-- template: -->
   <p>We have {{ num_langs }} languages</p>
   ```
2. Via the [`html_theme_options`](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-html_theme_options). This requires adding an option to `theme.conf` (you can create a theme by inheriting from a standard one):

   ```
   [options]
   num_langs = 1
   ```

   Then you can set `num_langs` in `conf.py` via `html_theme_options`:

   ```
   html_theme_options = {'num_langs': len(LANGS)}
   ```

   and use it in a template:

   ```
   <p>We have {{ theme_num_langs }} languages</p>
   ```

Comment: Wow, necro-answer!  Thanks. I have to admit I've nearly forgotten the original context and have moved on from that particular project.  I'll wait on accepting until your bounty has expired, though, in case there is indeed a different way to do it, since it would be nice to not have to create "themes", which I know even less about than generic Sphinx.

Comment: @kcrisman Yeah, I'd rather not to create themes myself, thus the bounty.

Comment: Found a better way of passing variables via html_context.

Comment: Perfect!  I am pretty sure this is the 'canonical' way so I'll accept even though I can't test it right now.  Thank you!

Comment: How do you find out the variables come with Sphinx? For instance, in "localtoc.html", I can directly write ``{{ toc }}`` and that works fine. But, where does this ``toc`` variable come from? How can I find others?

Comment: @xxks-kkk See [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#global-variables).